# Effciency: Dropping rows with the same timestamp while still having the median of second column for that timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bigdata

What I wanna do:
Column 'angle' has tracked about 20 angles per second (can vary). But my 'Time' timestamp has only an accuracy of 1s (therefore always about ~20 rows are having the same timestamp)(total rows of over 1 million in the dataframe).
My result shall be a new dataframe with a changing timestamp for each row. The angle for the timestamp shall be the median of the ~20 timestamps in that intervall.

My Idea:
I iterate through the rows and check if the timestamp has changed. 
If so, I select all timestamps until it changes, calculate the median, and append it to a new dataframe.
Nevertheless I have many many big data files and I am wondering if there is a faster way to achieve my goal.

Right now my code is the following (see below).
It is not fast and I think there must be a better way to do that with pandas/numpy (or something else?).

```
a = 0
for i in range(1,len(df1.index)):
    if df1.iloc[[a],[1]].iloc[0][0]==df1.iloc[[i],[1]].iloc[0][0]:
        continue
    else:
        if a == 0:
            df_result = df1[a:i-1].median()
        else:
            df_result = df_result.append(df1[a:i-1].median(), ignore_index = True)
    a = i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` here. Below, I made a simple dummy dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'angle' : [8,9,7,1,4,5,11,4,3,8,7,6]})

df1

  time  angle
0   1   8
1   1   9
2   1   7
3   1   1
4   1   4
5   1   5
6   2   11
7   2   4
8   2   3
9   2   8
10  2   7
11  2   6
```

Then, we group by the timestamp and take the median of the angle column within that group, and convert the result to a pandas dataframe.

```
df2 =  pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby('time')['angle'].median())
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2

    time angle
0   1     6.0
1   2     6.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.agg` after grouping function to select operation according to the column

```
df1.groupby('Time', as_index=False).agg({"angle":"median"})
```